# Refactor PHP Include Path

Tags: php

I mirrored a website and was able to add a PHP include to all PHP files through the use of Replace in Path technique. All PHP files on the same directory produces the following in the image:

[image]

Works as expected and I am able to interact with the navigation style. If I navigate to a file that is not in the same parent folder as the PHP include however (reports/index.php), then I get the following errors:

```
Warning: include(navigation.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in F:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\navigations\1\reports\index.php on line 148

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'navigation.php' for inclusion (include_path='F:\xampp\php\PEAR') in F:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\navigations\1\reports\index.php on line 148
```

Not sure if there is a productive way of being able to refactor all PHP includes or not without having to manually fix each page? I'm basically wanting to transform this:

```
<?php include("navigation.php"); ?>
```

Into this if say I am in the reports directory:

```
<?php include("../navigation.php"); ?>
```

Are there any editors or IDEs that can do this? I'm currently using PhpStorm.

Comment: You could store your root path to a defined constant `define('ROOT_PATH','full/root/path');` at the very top of your index file (or in a config.php that you include in the top). Then every sub-script that is included in your index file can include files like this  `include(ROOT_PATH."/navigation.php");` or `include(ROOT_PATH."/reports/navigation.php");`

Comment: Is that the root path to the `navigation.php` file and would I apply the defined constant to all pages?

Comment: Say you have an index.php. The starting point of your app. On the first line you can add `define('ROOT_PATH','full/root/path');` That should be the same path that you get from `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`. You can use the defined ROOT_PATH constant everywhere in your included sub-files like 'report/navigation.php', as long as you include them below define() in your index.php. If you are unclear still i can make an attempt to refactor what you have, provided you have a good reason why you want to split index files across specific task directories like /report/index.php

Comment: Got it working! Well kinda, I tested it in the reports index PHP file and it displays the HTML, but no CSS and JavaScript due to their paths thinking that they are in the reports directory. Here is the structure I have: 

index.php (Home Page) | 
reports (Folder) | 
--- index.php (Reports Page) | 
assets (Folder) (Contains CSS and JavaScript for the navigation I implemented) | 
navigation.php (Navigation Style) |

Not sure how I could fix this? I could just direct them to my remote server, but I'd have to upload any CSS and JavaScript for me to be able to see the changes.

Comment: Update, the navigation links are also thinking that they paths are in the reports directory. I'm just thinking, can `define('ROOT_PATH','full/root/path')` be applied to navigation links, CSS and JavaScript files to make the navigation style working no matter what folder I am in?

Comment: @userrandomuser A simple approach to this with css and js files is to have the path all relative to `/`. The good think `/` is relative to your webroot for these kind of files so you can do `/css/main.css` in every page and it will point to the same file.

Comment: Got it working! Thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using PhpStorm you can press `SHIFT + CTRL + R` to bring up a Find & Replace Dialog that is able to go through multiple files. Limit your selection to the path of the files if required and replace `"navigation.php"` with `"../navigation.php"`

Comment: Are you refereeing to the Replace in Path Dialog sorry? If so, wouldn't that replace all files that have `navigation.php` to `../navigation.php`, meaning only those that have one parent will be able to interact with the navigation? Apologises if I interpreted that wrong.

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late for this, as I've left for work yesterday. I am referring to the replace in path dialog where you can also define the scope of replacement. So if you have files in a subdirectory which have the wrong path you can replace all occurrences in that subdirectory which should yield the desired result. If not I misunderstood the question.